# Alternative option more direct to get the title atribute from an input in td?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the table (also http://jsfiddle.net/tW6qa/)

```
<table id="tabla_descuentos" class="tablesorter dataTable" cellspacing="0"> 
    <thead> 
        <tr role="row">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Activo</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Monto</th>
            <th>Inicio</th>
            <th>Termino</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="tienda_20" class="odd">
            <th class="">20</td>
            <th class=" sorting_1"><input type="image" title="Activo" src="images/icn_alert_success.png"></td>
            <th class="">General</td>
            <th class="">- $ 2</td>
            <th class="">2014-05-28</td>
            <th class="">0000-00-00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tienda_34" class="even row_selected">
            <th class="">34</td>
            <th class=" sorting_1"><input type="image" title="No activo" src="images/icn_logout.png"></td>
            <th class="">General</td>
            <th class="">-100 %</td>
            <th class="">0000-00-00</td>
            <th class="">0000-00-00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tienda_38" class="odd">
            <th class="">38</td>
            <th class=" sorting_1"><input type="image" title="No activo" src="images/icn_logout.png"></td>
            <th class="">General</td>
            <th class="">-99 %</td>
            <th class="">0000-00-00</td>
            <th class="">0000-00-00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tienda_13" class="even">
            <th class="">13</td>
            <th class=" sorting_1"><input type="image" title="No activo" src="images/icn_logout.png"></td>
            <th class="">General</td>
            <th class="">- $ 1.000</td>
            <th class="">0000-00-00</td>
            <th class="">0000-00-00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tienda_17" class="odd">
            <th class="">17</td>
            <th class=" sorting_1"><input type="image" title="No activo" src="images/icn_logout.png"></td>
            <th class="">Zapato</td>
            <th class="">- $ 123</td>
            <th class="">0000-00-00</td>
            <th class="">0000-00-00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I need the title attribute of the input in the 2nd th of the tr with class "row_selected"

I have this method but I think is not the most direct way.

```
$($($('.row_selected')[0].children[1].firstChild))[0].title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var title = $('tr.row_selected th:eq(1) input').prop('title');
```

Comment: Why not explain what this is doing? When I first learned what `eq` was about, it was fairly confusing...

Comment: Explanations are almost always useful, however [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) clearly explain what `:eq()` does.

Comment: thx I know `:eq` but I'm not used to use. Also `prop` dont work form e I use `attr`

Comment: prop() should work fine, as the title is both an attribute and a property, and in your own example you're getting the property.